# Which data source gives the present status of research in extending human lifespan?

Tags: book-recommendation, peer-review-journal

I have seen this book in Springer: 
[The Future Of Aging (Pathways to human life extension)](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789048139989)

That book seems to be of 2010; I am not finding any such new books, giving data on the present status of the research.

Which data source (journal articles, books, etc) gives the present status of research in extending human lifespan (longevity)?

I read Wikipedia ([Life Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_extension), [Immortality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortality)), they don't seem rigorous.

Comment: Are you asking for a more recent review paper/book of the topic?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yeah, I asked for a recent paper/book, to know on what conformations/actions in nutrition or exercise are to be made for becoming compatible for getting those life extending processes. I found certain summaries of the present status, which seem to be saying on there being none, now, allowing the life extension beyond what is normally known or possible from nutrition/exercise [Summary](https://www.reddit.com/r/gerontology/comments/89gest/the_current_state_of_the_pursuit_of_biological/?ref=share&ref_source=link). I....

Comment: ....have now shifted to other question: [Which sources give fitness programs for living longer?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/37512/23986)